# Is it possible to align a serie of label / textbox vertically with flowlayoutpanel?

Tags: winforms

I would like to align like this

```
label1 TextBox1
label2 TextBox2
label3 TextBox3
```

I set `FlowDirection` to `TopDown`
but how can I do to align `label1` with `TextBox1` horizontally ?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can do it. You have to remove the anchors of each control. In a FlowLayoutPanel, no anchors means middle vertical alignment.
I hope it helps.

Comment: didn't know about that! Added to my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Use `RightToLeft` instead of `TopBottom` in the FlowLayoutPanel and set `FlowBreak=True` to each TextBox.
To align vertically Labels and TextBoxes, set `Anchor=None` on all of them (as @Francisco says below)

[image: labels and textboxes aligned in a FlowLayoutPanel]

Comment: i don't understand the downvotes. The picture shows exactly what @programmernovice is asking for.

Comment: Setting `FlowBreak=false` on Label works for me, not TextBox

Answer (score 1):

FlowLayoutPanel does not support that behavior.
However, you could achieve the same result if you group each label/TextBox combo on e.g. their own panel and then set the FlowDirection to TopDown